# Unknown database - [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm writing my first project with Nestjs and I'm having trouble connecting to the database.
I installed mysql and set up the connection. TypeOrm creates the database itself? or do i have to do it with mysql?

```
Nest] 13684   - 07/24/2020, 12:44:50 AM   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +42ms
Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'my-database'
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      username: 'root',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'my-database',
      entities: [User],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

Comment: Do you have a database in your `mysql` server called "my-database"?

Answer (score 6):

First you should create the `my-database` database in your mysql server.

The TypeOrmModule create only tables (in in first time.)

1. Create database in your mysql server: `CREATE DATABASE myDatabase;` (I recommend, use this format: `myDatabase`.)
2. Restart the Nestjs.

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

> TypeOrm creates the database itself?

nope

> or do I have to do it with mysql?

yes

Comment: hmm but  when I login to mysql by console and use this command `mysql> CREATE DATABASE my-datadabse` i get `->` and nothing happens ... :/ Should I also create the columns using mysql? or will I do it in TypeORM?

Comment: `Should I also create the columns using mysql?` - nope. Try to define MySQL server port in typeorm config and use ip-like host

Comment: TypeOrm DOESN'T create a database? so what's the command `createDatabase` on queryRunner for?